# fixing Mysql Delimiter syntax error in testcontainers init script

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, testcontainers

I want to test a stored procedure with testcontainers. So I am initializing my container with an SQL script containing the definition of the stored procedure but I am getting this syntax error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initializer' defined in com.api.bankApi.services.TransactionServiceTest$TestConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.r2dbc.connectionfactory.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #7 of class path resource [schema.sql]: DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_amount decimal(17,2),IN trans_id varchar(255) ) exitSub:BEGIN DECLARE EXIT HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN DECLARE errNom INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [1064] [42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_am' at line 1
Caused by: org.springframework.data.r2dbc.connectionfactory.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #7 of class path resource [schema.sql]: DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_amount decimal(17,2),IN trans_id varchar(255) ) exitSub:BEGIN DECLARE EXIT HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN DECLARE errNom INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [1064] [42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_am' at line 1
Caused by: io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_am' at line 1
```

from mysql documentation the delimiter syntax seems to be correct I am wondering what could be the issue

this is the initializtion code

```
@TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer() {
            ConnectionFactoryOptions options = MySQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer.getOptions(database);

            ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
            initializer.setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactories.get(options));

            CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
            populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));
            populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("data.sql")));
            initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);

            return initializer;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: when I remove the stored procedure code the script runs ok. and the stored procedure is running fine in my local database as well

script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bank_account`;

CREATE TABLE `bank_account` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `balance` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transactions`;

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `error_log`;

CREATE TABLE `error_log` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_in` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `corrected_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `proc_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `node_id` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `err_no` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `err_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `row_no` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `value2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `text1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `text2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `long_text` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `err_log_time_idx` (`date_in`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE make_transaction(IN trans_type varchar(45),IN v_amount decimal(17,2),IN trans_id varchar(255) )
exitSub:BEGIN
 
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER for SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
          DECLARE errNom INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
          DECLARE errText VARCHAR (50);
          GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 errText = MESSAGE_TEXT, errNom = MYSQL_ERRNO;
          INSERT INTO error_log(proc_name,err_no,err_text,row_no,value1,long_text)
               VALUES ('make_transaction',errNom,errText,rowNo,concat('trans_id:',trans_id),'EXCEPTION');
        END;
        if v_amount < 0 then select 'negative amounts not allowed' as description; LEAVE exitSub; end if;
        if not exists(select `reference` from transactions where `reference`=trans_id)  then
            insert into transactions (transaction_type,amount,`reference`)
            values(trans_type,v_amount,trans_id);
            update bank_account set balance = if(trans_type='DEPOSIT',balance+v_amount,balance-v_amount);
            select 'success' as description;
            LEAVE exitSub;
        end if;
        select 'dupicate transaction' as description;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT:

after research I used testcontainers initscript its now executing without breaking but now it seems all other statements are being executed except creation of the stored procedure. because when i run the tests I get PROCEDURE does not exist error for tests that execute the procedure.

```
private static final MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8");
    static {
        try {
            final String script = Resources.toString(Resources.getResource("schema.sql"), Charsets.UTF_8);
            database.start();
            ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(new JdbcDatabaseDelegate(database,""), "schema.sql", script, false, false, DEFAULT_COMMENT_PREFIX, 
                    DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR, "$$", "$$$");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TransactionServiceTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

failed tests errors

```
TransactionServiceTest.depositFundsSuccess expectation "assertNext" failed (expected: onNext();
actual:onError(org.springframework.r2dbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
executeMany; bad SQL grammar [call make_transaction(?,?,?)]; 
nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcBadGrammarException: [1305] [42000] PROCEDURE test.make_transaction does not exist))
```

Comment: 'If you use the mysql client program ...you must redefine the delimiter ' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html ..you aren't using a mysql client program , have you tried without delimiters?

Comment: `DELIMITER` is **not** SQL statement but client command. It shouldn't present in your script. Read the manual for your language and MySQL accessing library/framework for correct delimiter changing in the batch script.

Comment: yes I have tried without and its not working. i'm not sure r2dbc has that delimeter functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the best way is to copy the sql file to the container and have it executed in the initialization of the container with /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. This is the recommendation by sql team. So this is how to achieve it.

```
 private static final MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8");
    static {
        try {
            database.withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("schema2.sql"), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql");
            database.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
```

Comment: That's also what the Testcontainers team would recommend from experiences with such use cases.